# Managing End of Line in Visual Studio Code ESLint extension across multiple OS

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm working on a React + Express + MongoDB project with repository on Github.
I'm using Windows as my main working station. However, I often commit some files with my macbook. Both using Visual Studio Code with same settings BTW.

I use auto formatting, format on save, and ESLint to keep a clean look before commit.

ESLint plugin highlights every end of line character everytime I pull from git.

In my .eslintrc.json file:

```
"rules": {
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "windows"
    ]
}
```

I tried to remove "windows" or change it to "unix", but still have same issues.
When commit to git, it says:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .eslintrc.json.
```

Is it a way to make the end of line LF/CRLF consistent across multiple platform inside Visual Studio Code environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed the end-of-line can be switched by clicking the CRLF words, and this is a global setting.

[image: Change end of line by clicking the CRLF button]

Comment: Can I add some kind of setting that every time I create a `.sh` file, sets the line ending to LF ? It is really annoying...